# How to remove a link from a specific area of a Jquery ListView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have the following situation: I am working on a C#/.NET web application that use **jQuery Mobile** view.

I have a view that show the following **ListView**:

```
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-split-icon="delete">
          @foreach (DataModel.Vulnerability.OVAL item in Model.VulnerabilityOVALs)
          {
              <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { Title = item.Title })">
                  <h2>@item.Title</h2>
                  <table style="width: 100%">
                  <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Definition ID</th>
                      <th>Title</th>
                      <th>URL</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Reference ID</th>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull((int)item.Id)</td>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.DefinitionID)</td>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.Title)</td>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.URL)</td>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.Status)</td>
                        <td>@MyHelper.decodeNull(item.ReferenceID)</td>
                </table>

            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteOval", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id, currentOvalId = item.Id, currentOvalTitle = item.Title})">Delete</a>

            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

As you can see this **ListView** is composed of some rows and each single row is divided in two main area: a first area that contains some textual information and a second area that contain the delete X button represented by:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteOval", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id, currentOvalId = item.Id, currentOvalTitle = item.Title})">Delete</a>
```

Now my problem is that if the user click on the first informative area it obtain the following error message and I want that this area is not clickable\linkable:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int64)' in
>   'MyWebApplication.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary
>   contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type
>   'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int64)'
>   in 'MyWebApplication.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry
>   for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int64)' in
>   'MyWebApplication.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters]
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo
>   parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +815
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +315
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +76 ..........................................................................................
>   ..........................................................................................
>   ..........................................................................................

How can I remove the HTML link from this fist informative area.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var html = $('ul li a:first').html();
$('ul li a:first').remove();
$('ul li').prepend(html);
```